# laravel 8 syntax error, unexpected '<' while calling component in View

Tags: php, laravel-8

Error showing on **F:\xampp\htdocs\ERP\resources\views/building/summary.blade.php:20**

following is code

```
        @foreach($records as $record)

        <tr>

            <td>{{ $record->id }}</td>

            <td>{{ $record->building->name }}</td>

            <td>{{ $record->name }}</td>

            <td>{{ $record->created_at }}</td>

            <td>

                <x-summary-action :view_path="{{ $view_path }}" :record="{{ $record }}">

                </x-summary-action>

            </td>

        </tr>

        @endforeach
```

And Component code is below

```
<a href="{{ route( $view_path . '.edit', $record->id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm edit" title="Edit">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

remove the curly brackets when you pass the variables to the components

```
<x-summary-action :view_path="$view_path" :record="$record">
</x-summary-action>
```

Comment: its gives me error Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [

Comment: may be you have a commented component so remove it. or may be you  have another <x-summary-action /> without passing values in the same page